# Standalone application asks end user to enter few details

Tags: java, excel, applet, resttemplate

I want to give an end user (layman) to enter name, age, qualification, and submit from his machine. And I want to save the details (in Excel/access) in my machine.
I have below conditions

1. I don't want to use any server/website in my machine.
2. I just give a jar to end user, he has to double click it and enter the details.

Suggest, can I implement the above scenario with java/applet/MS Excel or restTemplate/MS Excel

Please suggest any other approaches?

Answer (score 3):

I provide below the two approaches which you can easily implement without any server.

1. You can develop application using **Java Swing** or **JavaFx** and create a jar out of it. By double clicking, the UI will open up and user can enter the desired information. It will have some basic UI design. It is the recommended approach.
2. You can develop a very simple java application and can run in command prompt instead of UI. In the command prompt, it will ask for the desired information and user can enter. You have to **java console** for this.

Besides, the storage part, you can store the user entered information in Excel sheet using Apache POI framework, you can use XML or Json for simple storage.

Comment: How to point the file (which is located in mymachine) from client app

Comment: @Krishna, depending on how strong your requirement is `I don't want to use any server/website in my machine.` Is quite hard if you want users to modify a file on your machine. Bear in mind that even sharing the file via Windows means you are using a server on your PC even if you're not aware of it. You might be limiting yourself to interactions via email.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution that comes to mind is using an online service (does not require any server on your machine), both [google](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) and [microsoft](https://forms.office.com/) provide forms services. I'm sure there are others.

If you prefer a more complicated approach that does not use online services either, you can have a split Access file where you keep the data and the clients fill out the form, but you'd need to take care of data access from the clients (do they see the rest of the data or not?)

Comment: Thanks, might be this also fine. will try this option later